# Cannot hide forest generated subtrees

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, forest, overlays

I use beamer with the `forest` package and wanted to show the step-by-step construction of a tree. I am not quite familiar with Ti*k*Z and `forest`. I downloaded a solution to my problem and changed long label single letters and got the following.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table, dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %Remove navigation bar
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}
\forestset{
  visible on/.style={
    for tree={
      /tikz/visible on={#1},
      edge+={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{Same with forest}
    \begin{forest} baseline, for tree={draw,ellipse,align=center}
        [a
            [b,fill=yellow,for children={visible on=<2->}
                [c,fill=gray]
                [d
                    [e,fill=gray]
                    [f,fill=gray]
                ]
            ]
            [g,fill=gray]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I got two identical slides. The first slide does not hide the subtree it is supposed to hide.

What is wrong with the above LaTeX code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! I got two different slides when I compiled it. Could you perhaps include a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Could you please also provide a link to the solution you downloaded? (Note that depending on the source, you might be required to do this e.g. answers posted on SE typically require it.) But it also makes it easier to help.

Comment: I compiled your code pdflatex, lualatex and xelatex. I get a hidden sub-tree on the first slide in all three cases. Could you also post your log file? I also tried with an old version of `forest` (pre-version 2 release). I then compiled with TeX Live 2019. Different slides every time.

Comment: `visible on=<2->` should be used without `<>`, as these are added automatically. So: `visible on=2-`

Comment: @Lunjin Can you please a) add a screenshot of the result you get and b) add your .log file so we can see which engine you use and which version of the packages you have. I do get a hidden subtree with your code and texlive 2023: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkqC6.gif

Comment: @SašoŽivanović I believe you may be mistaken. `alt` adds them in, but it is defined with delimited arguments: `alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{...}`. As far as I know, that means the `<>` are required. Certainly I always include them. It's set up that way for consistency with Beamer's input.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses. I tried pdflatex and it worked. Previously,  I compiled before using latex -> dvips - ps2pdf and it did not work. In postscript, node texts are not hidden. In pdf, two slides show the same tree.

Comment: @cfr You're right, of course!

Comment: Did you read 'Producing Postscript Output' in the `pgf/tikz` manual (page 120 in my version). Opacity requires passing the `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` option to `ps2pdf`. (So do fadings.) How that works with Beamer, I'm not sure. As far as I know, Beamer fakes transparency ....